# Unable to access image from Resources to apply to an image button

Tags: maui

.Net8, Maui

I'm changing the button image depending on the status of the data behind it, like a custom checkbox.

The code in question is:

```
                    if (item.isActive)
                    {
                        var test = ImageSource.FromResource("Resources/Images/greencheck.png");
                        checkItem.selectedImage = test as ImageSource;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var test = ImageSource.FromResource("Resources/Images/greenchecknotselected.png");
                        checkItem.selectedImage = ImageSource.FromResource("Resources/Images/greenchecknotselected.png");
                    }
```

checkItem is a dataModel with this declaration in it:

```
    [Ignore]
    public ImageSource selectedImage { get; set; }
```

When I get this loaded, I will be binding the image in the XAML view.

I was catching a null exception on the CheckItem.selectedImage = ... so I added in the var test = ... to see if the image was getting loaded, and "test" appears to be loading the image.  However, when I apply it to the checkItem.SelectedImage, I still get the null ref exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

When I look at what's being loaded in "test", I see that the variable type is StreamImageSource, not ImageSource.  However, ImageSource.FromResource doesn't like the variable if I force it to StreamImageSource in the datamodel.

Any ideas on how to load the image into the datamodel?

Comment: just store the image name as a string in your model

Comment: OMG.  Why the heck was I making this so difficult?? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Jason, you can simply set the image name as a string in your model:

```
public class YourDataModel
{
    public string SelectedImageName{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: WAY easier than I was trying to do.